# I have a Ruby undefined local variable or method error

Tags: ruby, string, literals

When I try to run this code:

```
class Message
  @@messages_sent = 0
  def initialize(from, to)
    @from = from
    @to = to
    @@messages_sent += 1
  end
end

my_message = Message.new(chicago, tokyo)
```

I get an error that tells me that one of my parameters is undefined local variable. I was just trying to create an instance using `Message`, and was curious as to why this was not working. I thought this would work as I am calling the class.

Comment: Are `chicago` and `tokyo` defined and initialized somewhere?

Comment: The stack trace tells you exactly what line the undefined variable is on. Just spend some time to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

With your current code, you get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `chicago' for main:Object (NameError)
```

because the way you instantiated the `Message` class:

```
my_message = Message.new(chicago, tokyo)
```

`chicago` and `tokyo` are interpreted as variable or method that you did not actually define or declare, that's why you got that error.

#### Solution

I think, you just wanted to pass two string objects (putting `chicago` and `tokyo` in the quotes) as the arguments of `Message.new` call like this:

```
my_message = Message.new('chicago', 'tokyo')
```

This will solve your problem.

Hope this makes it clear why you are getting the error and how to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you!

Putting them as strings does solve the problem. But are Chicago and Tokyo not working as parameters? I thought typing them in would satisfy as the the from and to parameters for the initialize method in the class.

Comment: if you just type `chicago` that means you have to have a variable or method defined as `chicago`, if not, then you have to send it as string i.e. inside `quotes`. Let me know if that makes sense to you or if you have any other question.

Answer (score 1):

The 'undefined local variable' error is showing up because there's no value associated with *chicago* or *tokyo*. If you want to just pass them as strings, wrap them in quotation marks instead, like this:

```
class Message
    @@messages_sent = 0
    def initialize(from, to)
        @from = from
        @to = to
        @@messages_sent += 1
    end
end

my_message = Message.new("chicago", "tokyo")
```